# Double-depth pie chart in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

Does anyone know about a free software alternative to this one?:

https://codepen.io/akhbar/pen/yifbG

HTML:

```
<div id="chart" class="chart"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.chart {
  height: 400px; 
}
```

JS:

```
var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
    categories = ['MSIE', 'Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Safari', 'Opera'],
    name = 'Browser brands',
    data = [{
            y: 55.11,
            color: colors[0],
            drilldown: {
                name: 'MSIE versions',
                categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
                data: [10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81],
                color: colors[0]
            }
        }, {
            y: 21.63,
            color: colors[1],
            drilldown: {
                name: 'Firefox versions',
                categories: ['Firefox 2.0', 'Firefox 3.0', 'Firefox 3.5', 'Firefox 3.6', 'Firefox 4.0'],
                data: [0.20, 0.83, 1.58, 13.12, 5.43],
                color: colors[1]
            }
        }, {
            y: 11.94,
            color: colors[2],
            drilldown: {
                name: 'Chrome versions',
                categories: ['Chrome 5.0', 'Chrome 6.0', 'Chrome 7.0', 'Chrome 8.0', 'Chrome 9.0',
                    'Chrome 10.0', 'Chrome 11.0', 'Chrome 12.0'],
                data: [0.12, 0.19, 0.12, 0.36, 0.32, 9.91, 0.50, 0.22],
                color: colors[2]
            }
        }, {
            y: 7.15,
            color: colors[3],
            drilldown: {
                name: 'Safari versions',
                categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
                    'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'],
                data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14],
                color: colors[3]
            }
        }, {
            y: 2.14,
            color: colors[4],
            drilldown: {
                name: 'Opera versions',
                categories: ['Opera 9.x', 'Opera 10.x', 'Opera 11.x'],
                data: [ 0.12, 0.37, 1.65],
                color: colors[4]
            }
        }];


// Build the data arrays
var browserData = [];
var versionsData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    // add browser data
    browserData.push({
        name: categories[i],
        y: data[i].y,
        color: data[i].color
    });

    // add version data
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].drilldown.data.length; j++) {
        var brightness = 0.2 - (j / data[i].drilldown.data.length) / 5 ;
        versionsData.push({
            name: data[i].drilldown.categories[j],
            y: data[i].drilldown.data[j],
            color: Highcharts.Color(data[i].color).brighten(brightness).get()
        });
    }
}



// Create the chart
$('#chart').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market share, April, 2011'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total percent market share'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            shadow: false,
            center: ['50%', '50%']
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: '%'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Browsers',
        data: browserData,
        size: '60%',
        dataLabels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
            },
            color: 'white',
            distance: -30
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Versions',
        data: versionsData,
        size: '80%',
        innerSize: '60%',
        dataLabels: {
            formatter: function() {
                // display only if larger than 1
                return this.y > 1 ? '<b>'+ this.point.name +':</b> '+ this.y +'%'  : null;
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

I would need a pie chart which allows me to print a double depth pie, so that I can represent sub-segments. Is it possible to achieve this by using chart.js? I've tried searching everywhere but I didn't find anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "double depth"? Drill down? Also I'm sure the answer  to your question is in the HighCharts documentation.

Comment: Yes a drill down pie chart, sorry, I didn't know how to call it, that's what I'd want, but I mean.. I'm searching for a free software alternative, is it possible to do it with chart.js library?

Comment: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-drilldown

Comment: Yes I found that page, but I'm looking for a free alternative. Sorry, I actually said free software and that doesn't imply to be free to use.

Comment: Highcharts IS free to use.

Comment: Well that's in case if you're not a company, but I'm finding an alternative for mine since the minimum license for commercial use is 410$